# MySQL / PHP - Accented characters causing unusable data to be returned

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli, non-ascii-characters

Here is my code...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$sql = "SELECT product_name FROM my_table";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   foreach($row  as $key => $value) {
       //here, $value is populated but may contain a bad character
       $value = replaceAccents($value);
       //here, $value is now empty if it contained a bad character
   }
}
```

I have created all my tables with...

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

...and I have also called...

```
ALTER DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Most data is returned fine from the table, but if any field contains an accented character (e.g., `Crème`) then an unusable value is returned.

I haven't seen a problem like this - only vaguely similar ones, which have led to the above code / changes being implemented.

What is going wrong and how to fix??

Incidentally, if I do the above `sql` search in `phpmyadmin`, the problematic value (containing `Crème`) displays fine.

For completeness, here is my replaceAccents function...

```
function replaceAccents($str) {

    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: You know you are missing a closing quote `"` in `$sql = "SELECT product_name FROM my_table;`?

Comment: Cheers, fixed now - but just an SO typo. (It's not the cause of my problem, though.)

Comment: Probably not, otherwise you would be getting "other" problems not just "accented" :).